# Has anyone translated this to MicroPython - IR receiver reader

Tags: micropython, receiver

This website http://www.esp32learning.com/code/esp32-and-infrared-receiver-example.php uses Arduino code to read the data from an IR transmitter (remote control/wand).

Has anyone done the same for MicroPython?

Comment: on which board?

Comment: @NicoCaldo: Based on the linked website, an ESP32 and that particular IR module.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to think about the specifics of which board MicroPython is running on, and what kind of IR transceiver you have, however, at the time of answering there is [at least one MicroPython library](https://github.com/peterhinch/micropython_ir) that should help here.